# Autoplay Youtube video on mobile device

Tags: javascript, iframe, mobile, youtube

Instead of loading youtube embedded iframes, I'm loading images that look like youtube videos (to save load time). When one of those images is clicked, it's swapped with the actual youtube iframe.

Works perfectly, except on mobile the video does not autoplay after being rendered. I think this is disabled in iOS so that user doesn't incur data charges by videos auto playing.

My issue is that, from the users perspective, they've already 'clicked' the play button (i.e. they've given permission for the video to play). Is there any workaround to this behavior so I can autoplay the video when it loads?

I was thinking maybe something along the lines of `$('.youtube iframe').click()` where I could fake the user click, but not sure if that can be done in an iframe..

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you're actually saving any load time with your method. An embedded YouTube video doesn't actually load the entire video just by appearing on a page. It starts streaming the video when the user starts playing it.

Comment: But loading 20x iframes vs 20x small images is pretty huge

Comment: Is it though? Have you done actual testing to confirm that? All the embedded iframe loads is a small script and a thumbnail image.

Comment: I used this tutorial: http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/.  To my naked eye, it loads much much quicker. Like instantly vs 2-3 seconds

Comment: You may use Youtube Iframe API. When the user clicks on an  image, you call the API play methd. (Not 100% sur this will work)